# How to automatically generate getters and setters in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, shortcut

Is there a shortcut in Android Studio for automatically generating the getters and setters in a given class?

Answer (score 568, accepted):

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Insert</kbd> for Windows or <kbd>Command</kbd>+ <kbd>N</kbd> for Mac in the editor, you may easily generate getter and setter methods for any fields of your class. This has the same effect as using the Menu Bar -> <kbd>Code</kbd> -> <kbd>Generate...</kbd>

[image]

and then using shift or control button, select all the variables you need to add getters and setters

Comment: For those on Macs it's control + enter.

Comment: any possibility to create getter and setter such as ivar  _username and getter and setter are getUsername and setUsername?

Comment: On Mac Control+n

Comment: For java its working fine.But im using kotlin in android studio for app development.Then how to generate getter/setter like java?

Comment: how to generate getters and setters for Kotlin class

Comment: Command + N will not work on mac, use instead Control + N or Control + Enter

Answer (score 91):

for macOS, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> by default.

Right-click and choose "Generate..." to see current mapping. You can select multiple fields for which to generate getters/setters with one step.

See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-getters-and-setters.html

Comment: You can select multiple fields did the magic.

Answer (score 36):

**Android Studio & OSx** :

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> > <kbd>Generate</kbd> > <kbd>Getter and Setter</kbd>

**Android Studio & Windows** :

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> > <kbd>Generate</kbd> > <kbd>Getter and Setter</kbd>

Comment: Just tested on Windows Alt+Shift+S+R is not working and right click does not contain Source. Is it maybe a custom setup?

Comment: I have fixed the Win section! :)

Answer (score 13):

- create the variable
- right click
- select "Generate" and then select "Getter and Setter" option

[image: Right click menu]

Comment: Any shortcut for  **kotlin Constructors**? Alt + Ins not showing me generate Constructors option.

Comment: Did you try `Alt + Enter`?

Comment: for that case, I don't know what's going on. Did you post your problem in the Intellij forum?

Comment: When you find the solution, please, share it here.

Answer (score 10):

Android Studio & Windows :

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd>

[image: Image of Menu]

Comment: Your image hasn't appeared in the post correctly, and you have not completed an image description - it says 'enter image description here'.

Answer (score 9):

You can generate getter and setter by following steps:

- Declare variables first.

  click on <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> on keyboard placing cursor down to variable declaration part

  now select constructor and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on keyboard and click on <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create constructor.

  Now again placing cursor at next line of constructor closing brace , click <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> and select getter and setter and again press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all variables and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That's it. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 9):

Position the cursor under the variables -> right-click -> Generate -> Getter and Setter -> Choose the variables to make the get and set

or

Alt + Insert -> Getter and Setter -> Choose the variables

Comment: The question was if it is possible to generate getters and setters with a single shortcut, so not where you can find this option in a menu.

Comment: I did not understand.
Alt + Insert ->  Getter and Setter -> Choose the variables

Answer (score 6):

As noted [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60539), you can also customise the getter/setter generation to take prefixes and suffixes (e.g. m for instance variables) into account. Go to `File->Settings` and expand `Code Style`, select `Java`, and add your prefixes/suffixes under the `Code Generation` tab.

Answer (score 6):

Using **Alt**+ **Insert** or Right-click and choose "**Generate...**"
You may easily generate getter and setter or  Override methods in Android Studio.
This has the same effect as using the Menu Bar  **Code** -> **Generate**...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This answer deals with your question but is not exactly *an answer* to it. =) It's an interesting library I found out recently and I want to share with you.

---

[Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/index.html) can generate common methods, such as getters, setters, `equals()` and `hashCode()`, `toString()`, for your classes automatically. It replaces them with annotations reducing boilerplate code.  To see a good example of code written using Lombok watch a video on the main page or read [this article](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html).

> Android development with Lombok is easy and won't make your android application any 'heavier' because Lombok is a compile-time only library. It is important to [configure](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android) your Android project properly.

Another example:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class Profile {

  @Getter @Setter
  private String username;

  @Getter @Setter
  private String password;

}
```

Android development with Lombok is possible. Lombok should be a compile-time only dependency, as otherwise the entirety of Lombok will end up in your DEX files, wasting precious space. Gradle snippet:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
}
```

In addition you may want to add the [Lombok IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin) to support Lombok features in your IDE at development time. Also there is [Hrisey](https://github.com/mg6maciej/hrisey) library which is based on Lombok. Simply put, it's Lombok + Parcellable support.

Comment: Unfortunately, Project Lombok breaks in Android library projects.  It is unreliable right now.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky any proof?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Project Lombok works fine with Android. See [setup guide](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AndroidAccessors` Plugin of `Android Studio` to generate getter and setter without m as prefix to methods

Ex: mId;
 Will generate `getId()` and `setId()` instead of  `getmId()` and `setmId()`

[image: plugin screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac to get list of options to generate setter, getter, constructor etc

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use code=>generate=>getter() and setter() dialog  ,select all the variables ,generate all the getter(),setter() methods at one time.

Answer (score 1):

Another funny way

Type the parameter name anywhere in the object after definition, you will see setter and getter, Just select and click enter :)

I tried with Android Studio 2.3

Answer (score -1):

Right click on `Editor` then Select `Source -> Generate Getters and Setters` or press `Alt` + `Shift` + `S`
[image]

Comment: This is Eclipse. He asked for Android Studio.

Answer (score -2):

Just in case someone is working with Eclipse

Windows 8.1 OS | Eclipse Idle Luna

Declare top level variable  `private String username` Eclipse kindly generate a warning on the left of your screen click that warning and couple of suggestions show up, then select generate.[image]

Comment: The question was directed to Android Studio, not eclipse