# Required variable, found value?

Tags: java, android

I got an error by using this code

```
 holder.box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean newState = !arrEmps.get(position).isChecked();
            arrEmps.get(position).isChecked() = newState;
            Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(),
                    arrEmps.get(position).getName() + "check" + newState,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

the error line is

```
arrEmps.get(position).isChecked() = newState;
```

the error message is

```
Error:(86, 48) error: unexpected type
required: variable
found:    value
```

Comment: `isChecked()` calls a method that returns a value. You can't assign a new value to a method call. Look for a method called `setChecked` instead and use that.

Comment: `arrEmps.get(position).isChecked()` is a getter you can not assign a value to it . Add a Setter and use `arrEmps.get(position).setChecked()`

Answer (score 1):

*I think you are using a default method from a clickable item, if so read this, if not go on*

Referring to the [Clickable interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html), you can see that there are two methods:

> isChecked()

is a `getter` and it only returns the value of the checked variable, as you can see inspecting(ie: it tells you whether a `checkbox` is checked or not):

```
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}
```

There is also a `setter`,

> setChecked(boolean checked)

This setter set the value of the property of the checked state of the `clickable interface`. (ie: is set a `checkbox` as checked or not)

*If you are not using a default `clickable` item/view, but you have your own method*

If the object you are using is a custom one, create a `setter` for the property you want to set by adding a `setChecked(boolean value)` method

```
public void setChecked(boolean value){
  mValue = value;
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897215/how-to-automatically-generate-getters-and-setters-in-android-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) you can learn how to create getters and setters quickly

And I always reccomend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y) tutorial (imo the best) for learning android basics.

Hope this helps